# Historically accurate WW2 simulation

Tags: world-war-two

Does anyone of a good and historically accurate large scale WW2 simulation?  This could be either a computer or board game.

**Note**: *I am not sure if this should be on topic, of instead of downvoting if you think this is off topic, vote to close.  If you donw vote, please state how I could improve this question so that it is better on topic/better.  See [meta](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57/are-question-about-simulation-on-topic) as well.*

Comment: I'm voting to close, sorry. This isn't directly about history, and really belongs on the gaming site...

Comment: That is fine, I thought it would be off topic.

Comment: It would be off topic. I think chat is the best place for game recommendation questions.

Comment: next time maybe post this on meta first to avoid the hits to your rep ;)

Comment: @DForck42: I don't mind.  It gives new people an example of what is not on topic which is well worth the -4 hit I took.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hearts of Iron series is quite ok: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts_of_Iron_III

Comment: Many Paradox games are indeed a good way to simulate history.